# "findViewById" with for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, findviewbyid

it's my code:

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
ImageView img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img4);
ImageView img5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img5);
ImageView img6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img6);
ImageView img7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img7);
ImageView img8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img8);
ImageView img9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img9);
```

I d like to create something like this:

```
     for (int i=1; i<=9; i++) { 
ImageView img+i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img+i);}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do It like this. You can get drawable names from array stored in xml or code.

```
for (int i=1; i<=9; i++) { 

int id = getResources().getIdentifier("drawableName", "drawable", context.getPackageName());

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
}
```

Here "drawableName" is the name of your image and leave "drawable" as is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in the loop.
Basically R.id.img is a integer and 
if you do R.id.img + i, it will result in some random integer.