# Findviewbyid() in for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, findviewbyid

[I have tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29560273/8747279), but I didn't understand how to make custom names for my variables. Here is the code that I want to make shorter:

```
    TextView viewmt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt1);
    TextView viewmt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt2);
    TextView viewmt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt3);
    TextView viewmt4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt4);
    TextView viewmt5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt5);
    TextView viewmt6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt6);
    TextView viewmt7 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mt7);

    TextView viewtid1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tid1);
    TextView viewtid2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tid2);
    TextView viewtid3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tid3);
    TextView viewtid4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tid4);
    TextView viewtid5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tid5);
    TextView viewtid6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tid6);
    TextView viewtid7 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tid7);

    ImageView viewImage1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView viewImage2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView viewImage3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView viewImage4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    ImageView viewImage5 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    ImageView viewImage6 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    ImageView viewImage7 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
```

Comment: you can create dynamic Taxtview and Imageview and add on your Linear or Relative layout

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865350/5137352

Comment: If all/most your views are similar you should be using a RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.init `TextView`、`ImageView` array

2.add for loop

3.get id of the view

4.findViewById in the code

Try this .

```
TextView[]  textViews1 = new TextView[7];
TextView[]  textViews2 = new TextView[7];
ImageView[]  imageViews = new ImageView[7];

for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    String viewmt = "mt" + (i + 1);
    String viewtid = "tid" + (i + 1);
    String viewImage = "imageView" + (i + 1);
    int resIDmt = getResources().getIdentifier(viewmt, "id", getPackageName());
    int resIDtid = getResources().getIdentifier(viewtid, "id", getPackageName());
    int resIDImage = getResources().getIdentifier(viewImage, "id", getPackageName());

    textViews1[j] = ((TextView) v.findViewById(resIDmt));
    textViews2[j] = ((TextView) v.findViewById(resIDtid));
    imageViews[j] = ((ImageView) v.findViewById(resIDImage));
}
```

Comment: Can I access the variables outide the for-loop using their custom names?

Comment: You can use `imageViews[0]` 、`imageViews[1]` .And you can `ImageView[]  imageViews = new ImageView[7];` as global variables .And you can access all the place .

Comment: Can I type textViews1[1].setText(String);?

Comment: It shows nothing. This is my String: `final SharedPreferences smt1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("stot1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String mt1 = smt1.getString("stot1", "");`

Comment: Sorry ,I forgot to add `v.` in the code .You can try again.

Comment: And you can show the "hello world" to try first .Then add string to it .

Comment: It works with "hello world!", but not with my String

Comment: So it did not have data in `mt1` .You can check the `SharedPreferences` in your code .

Comment: After fixing my SharedPreference it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Good luck to you.@KjellØdegård

Comment: You are the most helpful guy I have ever met on the internet. Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240467/android-wont-provide-animation

Comment: I will check it for you tomorrow.@KjellØdegård

Answer (score 0):

You can't really define variable names at compile time.
The easiest solution will be to store all those views into an array or something like that. Here is an example:

```
class Component{
    TextView mt;
    TextView tid;
    ImageView img;
    public Component(TextView mt, TextView tid, ImageView img){
        this.mt = mt;
        this.tid = tid;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

.....
Component[] components = new Component[7];
for(int i = 0; i < components.length; i++){
   TextView mt = (TextView) v.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("mt" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName()));
   TextView tid = (TextView) v.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tid" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName()));
   ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("imageView" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName()));
   components[i] = new Component(mt, tid, img); 
}
....
```

And to access those you can use something like this

```
Component c2 = components[3];
c2.mt.setText(......);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the TextView's are listed in the correct order in your XML layout you can do something like this, assuming they are contained in a RelativeLayout but it should work the same for other Layout Class.

```
  RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout1);
  ArrayList<TextView> mTextViews = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < mLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
      View view = mLayout.getChildAt(i);
      if (view instanceof TextView)
            mTextViews.add((TextView)view);
  }
```

To get later one of the TexView  `myTextView = mTextViews.get[index];`